# How to access Aurora mysql from lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm currently trying to connect to an Aurora MySQL database from a lambda and retrieve record from a table.

All answers I researched and tried out require the use of Data api which is not supported anymore.(Including the ones on stack overflow)

Even the aws guides found are either outdated or for different scenarios

Notes:

- I'm using Aurora MySQL V3.01.0
- I'm using Burstable classes
- I'm using Typescript

Comment: Did you check out the docs on this? [Tutorial: Configuring a Lambda function to access Amazon RDS in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-rds-tutorial.html). What else have you tried and what are you struggeling with specifically?

Comment: I've checked this doc but the problem here is that it only specify the connection between lambda and aurora and totally neglects how to retrieve records from the tables in the database

Comment: There's example code in Python that shows you how to create a table, insert records into it and read them again. What exactly are you looking for here? A full step-by-step guide that tells you how databases work and how to interact with them is beyond the scope of a single stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to use the MySQL client that is compatible with the lambda runtime you're deploying. Here's the list that MySQL maintains.
https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Do you mean by client here a library like DynamoDB client library or something else?
If not please elaborate

Comment: Yes that's what the connector libraries are. You use the tool specific to the DB engine to retrieve records. Not something built by AWS.

Comment: Can't I just download it using npm? If not, then how am I suppose to integrate it with lambda?

Comment: Yes, you didn't specify which runtime you were using. But with node you can add the MySQL connector to your project with npm and then use it in your handler.

Comment: I have used the following commands:
npm install --save mysql
npm install --save-dev @types/mysql

Yet I still get the following error:
"Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'\nRequire stack:\n-"